# Getting special folder from remote machine

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

Is there a way to get a special folder from a remote machine?

I'm getting the local folder using this code:

```
$path = [environment]::getfolderpath("CommonApplicationData")
```

But I'd like to get it from other machine using a function like this:

```
$specialFolder = Get-RemoteSpecialFolder "MyRemoteMachine" "CommonApplicationData"

function Get-RemoteSpecialFolder
{
    param( 
        [string]$ComputerName,
        [string]$SpecialFolderName
    )
    Get-WMIObject ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: First hit on a Google search gave me this [Get environment variables in Windows remotely using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-environment-variables-baa1340f) script.. You can use with variable name "ProgramData"

Comment: Yes, I tried it out before post. But `ProgramData` Environment variable doesn't exists when I execute remotely `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Environment -ComputerName...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this info by reading the remote computers registry (you need permissions of course) like with the function below:

```
function Get-RemoteSpecialFolder {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

        [string]$SpecialFolderName = 'Common AppData'
    )
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        $regPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
        try {
            $baseKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $ComputerName)
            $regKey  = $baseKey.OpenSubKey($regPath)
            return $regkey.GetValue($SpecialFolderName)
        }
        catch {
            throw
        }
        finally {
            if ($regKey)  { $regKey.Close() }
            if ($baseKey) { $baseKey.Close() }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer '$ComputerName' is off-line or does not exist."
    }
}
```

You should be able to find these common environment variables with this:

> ```
> "Common Desktop"
> "Common Start Menu"
> "CommonVideo"
> "CommonPictures"
> "Common Programs"
> "CommonMusic"
> "Common Administrative Tools"
> "Common Startup"
> "Common Documents"
> "OEM Links"
> "Common Templates"
> "Common AppData"
> ```

P.S. Put the function in first, then call on it

```
$specialFolder = Get-RemoteSpecialFolder "MyRemoteMachine" "Common AppData"
```